# Java: Taking a string from user input and storing it in array, corresponding to an integer. Case: Employee Name and ID

Tags: java, arrays, terminal

I am working on a problem in Java that would ask the user for the ID and the last name of an employee and store each of the responses into an array for say, 20 employees. It does not have to be stored into one array, the arrays can be separate as in one for the employee id's and one for the last names, but I have to be able to print them neatly in the terminal.

The code I have below is a very simple idea of the way the program would be presented to the user. It simply asks "Enter the ID and last name of the employee." After that you enter the number, a space and then the last name. I can split the two using "nextLine().trim()" but I can't seem to store the string into an array.

```
    // IntStringSplit.java

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class IntStringSplit {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    String[] empName = new String[4];
    int[] empNum = new int[4];

    System.out.println( "Enter the ID and name: ");
    for( int counter = 0; counter <= 4; counter++ ) {
    int i = input.nextInt();
    String s = input.nextLine().trim();
    Arrays.fill( empNum, i );
    Arrays.fill( empName, s );
    }

    for( int i2 : empNum )
        System.out.printf( "The numbers are: %d%n", i2 );

    for( str s2 : empName )
        System.out.printf( "The names are: %s%n", s2 );
    System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Comment: Use `HashMap` instead of array.. `map.put(ID,Name)`....retrieve => `map.get(ID)`

Comment: `for( str s2 : empName )` is wrong, there is no `str` type in `Java`. You mean `String`

Comment: After further consideration, I recommend you use two arrays OR even better, create an object for each employee and store the objects in an array. Whichever you choose, I recommend you store the employee ID as a String (unless your twenty employees have ID's numbered 1-20). I'm guessing they're more random and potentially start with zero(s) (like my employee number IRL). Strings will keep that data intact better. E.g. an ID entered as 0154 becomes "0154" instead of 154 - it won't lose the leading zero. And not using the ID as an array index will save loads of space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my suggested correction below:

- `Array.fill()` fills the entire array with one value. Use `arrayName[index] = value;` syntax to add one value at a time.
- Make sure your counter stops before it reaches the length of the array. Last index is array length - 1. Less than 4 or less than or equal to 3 in your case. (Would be better to use `arrayName.length` instead of a number, though.)

  ```
  // IntStringSplit.java

  import java.util.Scanner; import java.util.Arrays;


  public class IntStringSplit {

      public static void main( String[] args ) {

          Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

          String[] empName = new String[4];
          int[] empNum = new int[4];

          System.out.println( "Enter the ID and name: ");

          for( int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++ ) {
              int i = input.nextInt();
              String s = input.nextLine().trim();
              empNum[counter] = i;
              empName[counter] = s;
          }

          for( int i2 : empNum )
              System.out.printf( "The numbers are: %d%n", i2 );

          for( str s2 : empName )
              System.out.printf( "The names are: %s%n", s2 );

          System.out.println();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: That was it! Thank you! J.D. you're awesome, that little bit of code took me to the next level!

Answer (score 2):

`for( str s2 : empName )` is wrong, use

`for( String s2 : empName )` instead. Also, a Array is not the ideal way to store such data, because the length is fixed and it can only contain on value. You can use a hasmap instead. It connects a key (the id) to the value (the last name).

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>;
map.put(id, lastName);
```

Comment: Thank you much for the response; I do not know how to use hashmaps as of yet; from the documentation it does look better tho. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: +1 for realizing - unlike me - that the Employee ID's might not correspond to the number of employees. I.e. the fifth employee might have an ID like 0235 for whatever reason. You're right - that doesn't fit nicely into an array.
Furthermore, String is probably a better container for the ID as it could start with zero(s) - mine does!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the the class i have written to take input from the User and retrieve the data after taking inputs.

Inputs needs to be in this format:  
Enter the Employee Number followed by Last name: 
23 abc

Enter the Employee Number followed by Last name: 
21 bfs

Enter the Employee Number followed by Last name: 
34 fs

Enter the Employee Number followed by Last name: 
23 fig

Enter the Employee Number followed by Last name: 
23 78

Results would be like this:
Employer Number is: 23 Last Name is: abc

Employer Number is: 21 Last Name is: bfs

Employer Number is: 34 Last Name is: fs

Employer Number is: 23 Last Name is: fig

Employer Number is: 23 Last Name is: 78

Code:

```
    package com.test;

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;



    public class IntStringSplit {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
    int numberOfLoops= 5;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Employee> myArray = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    int counter=0;
    while(counter<numberOfLoops){
    System.out.println("Enter the Employee Number followed by Last name: ");

    String employeDetails = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] splited = employeDetails.split("\\s+");
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(splited[0]));
    emp.setLastName(splited[1]);
    myArray.add(emp);
    counter++;

    }
    scanner.close();

   for(Employee emp: myArray){
  System.out.println("Employer Number is: "+emp.getNumber() + " Last Name is: " + emp.getLastName());
  }

   }

  static class Employee {
    Integer empNumber;
    String lastName;
    public int getNumber() {
        return empNumber;
    }
    public void setNumber(Integer empNumber) {
        this.empNumber = empNumber;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    }
  }
```

Comment: I like how you create an object for the employee, but I'd recommend a little more thought about how the object should work. The OP's problem doesn't list any need to change either the ID or the last name in the program so I think we should keep it simple and use a constructor that sets both at object creation. Then we can leave out the setter methods, and save several lines of code there and in the main program. ([YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it))

Comment: Thanks J.D. It makes sense.